# WebLogic error: Unable to acquire JDBC Connection

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee, weblogic, weblogic12c

I have a strange exception with WebLogic 12.2.1.3, Hibernate 5.3, Sprnig Data JPA, and Java EE.

I have a database, and a Generic JDBC Data source in weblogic, with the JNDI name of `jdbc/UsersDS.`

When I'm trying to list the entries in it, I get a really long exception, which I don't really want to paste in here, so I used Pastebin: [Here it is](https://pastebin.com/dBWHY3R5). Pls let me know, if I should instead paste it here anyway.

I have the exact same setup for this artefact, then what I have for another one, which connects to the same server, but to a different database, with different user. That one works like a charm, this one doesn't. The only difference I can think of being related to this is the fact that the artefact, where I get the error from has Spring Data Redis included as a dependency alongside Spring Data JPA.

Persistence.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<persistence xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_2.xsd"
             version="2.2">
    <persistence-unit name="UsersDS" transaction-type="JTA">
        <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
        <jta-data-source>jdbc/UsersDS</jta-data-source>
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update"/>
            <property name="hibernate.transaction.factory_class"
                      value="org.hibernate.transaction.JTATransactionFactory"/>
            <property name="hibernate.transaction.manager_lookup_class" value="javax.transaction.TransactionManager"/>
            <property name="hibernate.transaction.jta.platform" value="Weblogic"/>
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL95Dialect"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Ui.: One more thing that might be related to the problem is because I have both Spring Data JPA and Redis on the classpath, I had to mark the JpaRepository interface as a `@NoRepositoryBean`, because I'd get a duplicate otherwise. So I have a method to produce the CDI Repository Bean:

```
    @Inject
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    @Produces
    @RequestScoped
    public UserRepository userRepository() {
        return createRepository(UserRepository.class);
    }

    private <T extends Repository> T createRepository(Class<T> repositoryClass) {
        RepositoryFactorySupport factory = new JpaRepositoryFactory(entityManager);
        return factory.getRepository(repositoryClass);
    }
```

UI2.: I also wrote some integration tests with a H2 in memory database and everything runs smoothly

Comment: I found this line in the log: `SessionFactoryRegistry - Not binding SessionFactory to JNDI, no JNDI name configured` Does this mean anything? The table in the database does get created tho

Comment: may you post also spring configuration?

Comment: there is no spring configuration. This is a CDI environment

Comment: So you want to use `jdbc/UsersDS` but have `jdbc/FiveshellyD` in your configuration. Which is wrong.

Comment: yeah, sorry I forgot to edit that, I fixed the config couple minutes after posting. I replaced UsersDS to FiveshellyDS, because I know that that datasource works, because it works with the other artefact

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have the solution, and it's probably some workaround, or sg, but I have nothing else.

So what happened, was I had (by default) in the weblogic datasource global transactions on. Switching it off solved the problem